# Undefined method `merge' for Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting undefined method `#merge` however `#merge` method works good in the second block. What's wrong with Block 1?

```
# Block 1
network_posts = []
@networks.each do |network|
  network_posts << network.posts.as_json.merge('pic' => network.pic.url) 
end
```

```
# Block 2
network = []
@networks.each do |network|
  network << network.as_json.merge('pic' => network.pic.url) 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `as_json` method is not obligated to return a Hash. It can return anything it wants, a string, a number, a boolean value, or even, as in this case, an array. Assuming it supports `merge` is a mistake.

Since this appears to be operating on a collection (`network.posts`) that will be an array. Merging that in isn't practical. You could merge in on each record's `as_json` result:

```
network.posts.map do |post|
   post.as_json.merge(...)
end
```

Comment: hey, but your code inside merge part is missing, how should it fetch `network.pic.url` if you `map` it by `|post|`

Comment: It'll work just the same as `network` is valid in that context. It's only removed for brevity.